# Как правильно обратиться к объекту в массиве в объекте?

Tags: javascript

Имеется структура такого вида:

```
[ 
  {
    "Emails": [{ 
      "id": 9, 
      "user_id": 1, 
      "email": "abba9@mail.ru"
    }],
    "Something": [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "some"
    }]
  }
]
```

Как правильно обратиться к значению email?
На данный момент я сделал перебор по массиву и пробовал обратиться как-то так:

```
//.foreach(item)

item["Emails"][0]["email"]
```

Но так я не получаю искомое

Comment: Если статичное обращение к именам свойств, то без квадратных скобочек можно: `data.forEach(item => { console.log(item.Emails[0].email, item.Something[0].name); });` - тут подразумевается что вся структура в переменной `data`.

Comment: _«На данный момент я сделал перебор по массиву»_ - А перебор вообще нужен, объектов первого уровня вложенности (элементов самого верхнего массива) может быть несколько? Из текста это не совсем понятно.

Comment: Объект первого уровня - это объект строки из sql таблицы. Их может быть много

Comment: Странно, обращаюсь к item.Emails - всё ок. К item.Emails[0] - всё ок. Вижу эти объекты в браузере. При обращении к item.Emails[0].email ->  TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined

Comment: Ну мы-то в консоли браузера этих данных не видим, так что хз. Может там есть еще один уровень вложенности, а может наоборот где-то уровня вложенности "не хватает" относительно того что в вoпросе написано... это если исключать самый банальный вариант разнообразных опечаток (включая смесь латиницы и кириллицы, типа `еmаil`). Бэкэндеры иногда такие руко*пы...

Comment: В общем, натупил малость. На самом деле значение получал и по своему запросу. Просто в простыне ошибок не увидел, что часть мейлов распечатывается, а ошибку дают те, где undefined. Надо внимательнее логи смотреть в общем
Всем спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Смею допустить, что Emails как массив тоже может содержать не один элемент.

```js
let arr = [ 
 {
  "Emails": [{ 
     "id": 9, 
     "user_id": 1, 
     "email": "abba9@mail.ru"
    },{ 
     "id": 8, 
     "user_id": 3, 
     "email": "abddw222ba9@mail.ru"
    }],
  "Something": [{
     "id": 1,
     "name": "some"
    }]
 },
 {
  "Emails": [{ 
     "id": 9, 
     "user_id": 1, 
     "email": "accc333bba9@mail.ru"
    },{ 
     "id": 8, 
     "user_id": 3, 
     "email": "abdd454ty3w222ba9@mail.ru"
    }],
  "Something": [{
     "id": 1,
     "name": "some"
    }]
  }
]

const test1 = () => {
   return arr.map(({Emails}) => Emails.map(e => e.email));
}

const test2 = () => {
   return arr.reduce((acc,{Emails}) => {acc.push(...Emails.map(e => e.email)); return acc;} ,[])
}

console.log(test1())
console.log(test2())
```

Answer (score -1):

Сначала обратитесь к массиву:

```js
const obj = [{
    "Emails":
    [{
        "id": 9,
        "user_id": 1,
        "email": "abba9@mail.ru"
    }],
    "Something":
    [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "some"
    }]
}];
console.log("email: %s", obj[0].Emails[0].email);
obj.forEach(function(item){
    console.log("in foreach email: %s", item.Emails[0].email);
});
```